# how to have a change event on a list object?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

Here is my JSP code in which I am iterating through a list of classes..

```
<c:forEach items="${student.classes}" var="item" varStatus="status">
<tr>
<td><form:input path="classes[${status.index}].instructorName" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
<td><form:input path="classes[${status.index}].instructorGender" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
<td><form:input path="classes[${status.index}].instructorExp" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Lets say, I have a 3 objects in my list and its going to show the page with 3 rows with the details. If the user changes second row, I need to send that index to my controller so that I can update the database with updatetime of that particular row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a server-side url called /update?id=[id to update],
and each of your items has a field called id, something like this should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateUpdateTime(id) {
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","/update?id="+id,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<c:forEach items="${student.classes}" var="item" varStatus="status">
<tr>
<td><form:input onchange="updateUpdateTime(${item.id})" path="classes[${status.index}].instructorName" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
<td><form:input onchange="updateUpdateTime(${item.id})" path="classes[${status.index}].instructorGender" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
<td><form:input onchange="updateUpdateTime(${item.id})" path="classes[${status.index}].instructorExp" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: yes...there is an id but, it will same..that id will have three or more rows...using id.index is the only way to update..but, getting that id.index back to controller is what giving me issues?